# Help with finding coefficient of $x^k$ in $(x^2 - \frac{1}{x})^{100}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

So $(x^2 - 1/x)^{100}$

Through the binomial formula $(x^2 - 1/x)^{100}$ is:

$$\sum_{j = 0}^{100} C(100,j) (x^{2})^{j} (1/x)^{100-j}$$

$$\sum_{j = 0}^{100} C(100,j) (x^{2})^{j} (-1)^{100-j}(x^{-1})^{100-j}$$

$$\sum_{j = 0}^{100} C(100,j) (x)^{2j} (-1)^{100-j}(x)^{-100+j}$$

$$\sum_{j = 0}^{100} C(100,j) (x)^{3j-100} (-1)^{100-j}$$

Let k = $3j-100$

Then j = $(k+100)/3$

And k should any value between 0 and 100 inclusive such that k is a whole number.

I'm not sure what's wrong in how I proceeded, I know the correct answer should be:

$(-1)^{(200-k)/3} C(100,(200-k)/3)$

But I'm not sure where I went wrong

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{200-k}3+\frac{100+k}3=100\implies{100\choose\frac{200-k}3}={100\choose\frac{100+k}3}$$

Comment: how do i get (200-k)/3 from the series of simplifications in the first part of the post? i can't just pull that figure out of nowhere.

Comment: Starting from the last sum in your post, (200-k)/3 **IS** pulled out of nowhere (but the formula is correct).

Answer (score 1):

It's the coefficient of $x^{k+100}$ in $(x^3-1)^{100}$. And then it's the coefficient of $x^{(k+100)/3}$ in $(x-1)^{100}$.

Comment: how do i get (200-k)/3 from the series of simplifications in the first part of the post? i can't just pull that figure out of nowhere.

Comment: This is exactly how I would have done it - couldn't agree more.

Comment: I think you are asking how to get from $${100\choose(k+100)/3}{\rm\ to\ }{100\choose(200-k)/3}$$ and the answer is, by remembering $${n\choose r}={n\choose n-r}$$